# Есть ли нумерация элементов в множествах (наборах) и как обратиться к определенному элементу множества?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Заметил, что при выводе элементов из множества они каждый раз выводятся с разной нумерацией порядка, как тогда можно обратится к определенному элементу множества?

p.s. Может кому-нибудь будет полезно: Заметил, что в 3.x.x версии, если во множестве только переменные типа int, то их всегда выводит упорядоченно от наименьшего до наибольшего.

Comment: Но зачем? Если нужно привязать какую-то информацию к уникальным объектам, то проще использовать словарь.

Comment: Было интересно существует ли такая возможность в питоне.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для упорядоченного множества есть специальный модуль:

```
from ordered_set import OrderedSet

print(set('abracadabra'))
print(set([5, 5, 4, 6, 7]))

print(OrderedSet('abracadabra'))
print(OrderedSet([5, 5, 4, 6, 7]))
```

Вывод:

> {'b', 'c', 'r', 'a', 'd'}
>
> {4, 5, 6, 7}
>
> OrderedSet(['a', 'b', 'r', 'c', 'd'])
>
> OrderedSet([5, 4, 6, 7])

Answer (score 2):

Множество как математический термин *по определению неупорядоченно,* например:

```
{1, 2} == {2, 1}
```

Питон строго придерживается этой концепции, значит, *невозможно полагаться на какой-либо специальный порядок,* хотя вы какой-то для чисел отследили — это только *внутреннее дело имплементации,* которое может измениться с другой версией Питона *без предупреждения.*

Значит, когда вы хотите прямой доступ к элементу (например для его позиции в структуре), нужно использовать *другие структуры,* например список, упорядоченное множество (`ordered_set`) или словарь, как вам уже посоветовали в других ответах.

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> s = {1, 2, 3}
>>> print (s)
{1, 2, 3}
>>> print (s[0])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable
>>>
```

Если нужен упорядоченный список, то нужно брать `tuple` или `list`.

Answer (score 0):

Если совсем коротко, то на прямую, никак.

Выход: создать из множества список.

```py
a = set('this is my set')   # {'i', 'm', 'e', 'h', 't', 'y', 's', ' '}
a[0]                        # TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable

b = list(a)                 # ['i', 'm', 'e', 'h', 't', 'y', 's', ' ']
b[0]                        # i
```